Make a function available to the browser's console in node
I'm building a web app using node.js. I need to declare a function in my TypeScript code that will then be available from the browser (for interop purposes).
Code Snippet
// index.ts 
// ... 
export function doThing(x: number, y: number) : void {
    // ...
}

What I've Tried
Initially, I just tried calling my function from the browser console. This didn't work; I got the error Uncaught ReferenceError: doThing is not defined.
My next idea was to add the export keyword to doThing and try again, however this also didn't work.
Edit: Workaround(?)
As repeated in my answer to this question, I managed:
(window as any).addPinAt = addPinAt;

This feels like a hacky workaround to me, and I remain open to more highly recommended solutions.
Question
What can I do to a function in index.ts to make it callable from the browser console?

globalThis.doThing = doThing inside the module

I’m not sure what you think you’re doing—this isn’t “interop”, the code is still running on the browser. Sharing code isn’t the same as interop, this is just putting code in the global scope. The server and client environments/contexts are still isolated.

@DaveNewton to clarify: The reason that I'm doing this is so that I can then "call" this function from another language, which has access to the browser. The note was to provide the context that I'm not trying to pollute the global space for no reason, which I'm aware is a bad idea, though I communicated that poorly in my question.

I’m sorry but I still don’t understand. NodeJS runs on the server. No browser code runs on the server. If you hang something on  window it’s running on the browser whether you call it from something controlling the browser (like a selenium) or the browser itself.

@DaveNewton apologies for my troubles in explaining, I'm completely new to the world of JavaScript and just stumbling through. There is no server in my use case. I believe it's something to do with using webpack - I run "npm run build", and it generates some code in dist/bundle.js, which is then referenced from index.html.

So this feels a little hacky, but I ended up doing:
(window as any).doThing = doThing;

